# SQL query and saving the result in a new table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL query like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM abc.dfg AS 'a'
WHERE a.limit > 100
AND a.size < 5
```

I would like to save this result automatically in a table named "result" in my SQLite DB. So that it is saved if I run it and overwrites the resulting table "result" if I run the query again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE TABLE AS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CREATE TABLE AS and drop if exists

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Schema.Result
   
 CREATE TABLE Result AS
    SELECT a.*
    FROM abc.dfg AS 'a'
    WHERE a.limit > 100
    AND a.size < 5
```